# binary '<<' : no operator found which takes a left-hand operand of type 'std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char>>'

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, operator-overloading, ostream, ostringstream

There is a function which gets std::ostream& as an arguments and performs some operations:

```
inline std::ostream& my_function(std::ostream& os, int n) {
      // some operations
      return os;    
}
```

And there is another function that calls `my_function`:

```
void caller_function(int  n) {
    std::ostringstream ostsr;
    ostsr << my_function(ostsr, n);
}
```

The visual studio 2015 compiler reports an error:

```
error C2679: binary '<<' : no operator found which takes a left-hand operand of type 'std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char>>'
```

std::ostringstreamm has an inherited and overloaded `operator<<` which takes manipulator function for this case tha manipulator function is `my_function`
The overloaded operator<<:

```
ostream& operator<< (ostream& (*pf)(ostream&));
```

So what is the issue and how to fix it?

Comment: `my_function(ostsr, n)` is not a manipulator function. It's a stream reference. `my_function` *is* a function but the signature is wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your function does not match `ostream& (*pf)(ostream&)` but `ostream& (*pf)(ostream&, int)`. You would have to bind the second argument somehow. Using lambdas for that purpose will be difficult though because if you capture (and use) anything, [such as `n` in your case](https://godbolt.org/z/8-TUKc), the lambda can no longer decay to a function pointer [as it otherwise could](https://godbolt.org/z/iJDtqt).

I don't see a reentrant way you could use the manipulator overload with runtime parameters like `n`, as anything matching `ostream& (*pf)(ostream&)` cannot have state (or at best rely on some global, which is ugly and unsafe) and has no way of getting that additional information through parameters either.

(As **n.m.** pointed out in the comments, you are also not passing the function to `<<` but its return value, which is not what you intended).

Comment: Or one could just write `my_function(ostsr, n);` (no `<<`) and call it a day.

Comment: it starts to work when I have call my_function like this:  ostsr << &my_function(ostsr, n); and I don't know why because there are no operator that takes std::ostream as a left operand.

Comment: @user37014 What you are doing there is taking the pointer to the returned `std::ostream&`. You will end up printing the pointer (after calling the function). I don't think that's what you want.

Comment: How else this can be done? When I write std::ostream l = my_function (ostsr, n) and then ostsr  << l; the compiler reports: "attempting to reference a deleted function"

Comment: @user37014 What you are trying to do there is create a copy (named `l`) of `ostsr` (returned by `my_function`). The compiler tells you that making copies of it is not allowed. To get an answer to "how else can this be done", you'd have to first describe what "this" is. As mentioned in my answer, there is no way to bring together `my_function(ostream&, int)` and the `ostream& (*pf)(ostream&)`. But presumably that's not your actual goal - you want to achieve some larger objective (which you have not explained). See [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem).